# Edit object in edit screen and sync updated object in first screen (list of object screen)

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a list of class user showing with StateNotifier in one screen. Clicking on any item, opens the edit screen of that user.
I have 2 questions to ask:

1. Should I send user object In another screen and edit the user or create state provider (without auto dispose) of single object and set it before opening edit screen and access it on another screen.
2. After edit the user, how to sync updated user object in user list screen (first screen).

Please feel free to ask any further detail.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I send user object In another screen and edit the user or
> create state provider (without auto dispose) of single object and set
> it before opening edit screen and access it on another screen.

No, just send user object to edit screen, then after you edit done, pass data back to list screen by `Navigator.pop(context, editedUser);`

> After edit the user, how to sync updated user object in user list
> screen (first screen).

On list screen :

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'yourEditScreen', arguments: editUser).then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        //update your state list;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't cover how you send data between screens because it depends on what **state manager** you are using and there are actually many ways.

Assuming that you are on screen 1 after finishing screen 2, you have **a list of old objects** and **a new object that has been modified**. now you'll want to **inject the changes into the old list object** and **call the update state**

Example:

```dart
var objects = [{...}];

return ListView(
  children: objects.map((object) {
    final index = objects.indexOf(object);
    onPressed() {
      // handle will call when screen2 poped
      handleEditedData(editedObject) {
        // check object was edited and differences with old object (can override operator ==)
        if (editedObject != null && editedObject != object) {
          setState(() {
            // replace old object by editedObject with the index
            objects[index] = editedObject;
          });
        }
      }
      
      // push screen2 and wait to data from screen2 (using .pop with editedObj as parameter)
      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushNamed('screen2route', arguments: object)
          .then(handleEditedData);
    }

    return ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text('edit'));
  }).toList(),
);
```